# How to prevent endpoint clashing while developing REST API in Express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I have the following rest api to get orders in express application

`http://localhost:2000/api/orders/chemists?orderBy=date&startDate=date1&endDate=date2`

`http://localhost:2000/api/orders/chemists?orderBy=chemist&startDate=date1&endDate=date2`

my Queries are as follows...

```
router.get("/chemists?orderBy=date", ...)
router.get("/chemists?orderBy=chemist", ...)
```

When I make a query with postman the top one is executing but not the bottom one? Any suggestions as to how to structure by REST API. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't put the query string into the route definition with Express.  If you're going to stay with that URL structure, then you need one route handler and use an `if` based on the values in `req.query`:

```
router.get("/chemists", (req, res) => {
    if (req.query.orderBy === "date") {
         // handle /chemists?orderBy=date
    } else if (req.query.orderBy === "chemist") {
         // /chemists?orderBy=chemist
    } else {
         // handle neither chemist or date specified
    }
});
```

If you really, really wanted separate routes for them in Express, you'd have to change the URL design into something like:

```
 /chemists/date
 /chemists/person
```

Which you could then declare a separate route for each.  Since, this sort order is really just an attribute of the request (same resources being requested either way), it makes more sense (in a REST design) for it to be the first option in the query string with one route.

Comment: Thank you, actually, after a while this is exactly what I did. Thanks for the answer though!